# Symmetries of proton-neutron interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, neutrons, protons, pions

I am following Sidney Coleman's lectures of Quantum field theory, where in ch 24 (page 509) he wrote down the non-derivative pseudoscalar type interaction Lagrangian between the proton $p$ and neutron $n$ mediated by neutral pion $\pi^{0}$ and charged pions $\pi^{+} \& \pi^{-}$:

$\mathcal{L} = g_{P} \bar{p} i\gamma_{5} p \phi_{0} + g_{N} \bar{n} i \gamma_{5} n \phi_{0} + g_{C}\bar{p} i \gamma_{5} n \phi_{+} + g_{C}^{*}\bar{n} i \gamma_{5} p \phi_{-} + \cdots$

where $\bar{p}$ and $p$ are proton Dirac fields, $\bar{n}$ and $n$ are neutron Dirac fields, $\phi_{0}$ is the neutral pion field, and $\phi_{+}$, $\phi_{-} = \phi_{+}^{\dagger}$ is the charged pion fields, and $g_{P}$, $g_{N}$ and $g_{C}$ are just some coupling constants.

My question is that he said that this is the Lagrangian consistent with Lorentz invariant, parity and **electric charge conservation**. However, I am not quite sure whether this model has a conserved electric charge. If we have a conserved electric charge, we should be able to conceive a continuous transformation like

$p \to e^{i \alpha} p$

$\bar{p} \to e^{-i \alpha} \bar{p}$

$n \to e^{i \alpha} n$

$\bar{n} \to e^{-i \alpha} \bar{n}$

$\phi_{0} \to  \phi_{0}$

$\phi_{+} \to e^{i \alpha} \phi_{+}$

$\phi_{-} \to e^{-i \alpha} \phi_{-}$

where *all* the phases $\alpha$ are same. This will allow us to write down an overall conserved charge for this theory. However, the above transformation does not leave the $\mathcal{L}$ invariant. I am wondering what kinds of charges are conserved in this $\mathcal{L}$, and what continuous symmetry allows us to construct it.

I know certainly if I only have

$p \to e^{i \alpha} p$

$\bar{p} \to e^{-i \alpha} \bar{p}$

or

$p \to e^{i \alpha} p$

$\bar{p} \to e^{-i \alpha} \bar{p}$

$n \to e^{i \alpha} n$

$\bar{n} \to e^{-i \alpha} \bar{n}$

Then these two sets of transformation will leave $\mathcal{L}$ invariant and we can write down the conserved charge, however this will make the charge of the pions not a conserved quantity. I am also aware that this $\mathcal{L}$ does respect charge conjugation symmetry, but I suppose that charge conjugation is a discrete symmetry so it doesn't imply anything about charge conservation?

All in all, I would like to ask what is the charge that is conserved in the above $\mathcal{L}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field $f$ with charge $q$ should transform as
$$
 f\to \exp(iq\alpha)f.
$$
Since $\phi_0$ and $n$ both have charge $0$, they should not be affected by the transformation. The correct transformation is
\begin{align*}
 p &\to \exp(i\alpha)p \\
 \bar p &\to \exp(-i\alpha)\bar p \\
 n &\to n\\
 \bar n &\to \bar n\\
 \phi_0 &\to \phi_0\\
 \phi_+ &\to \exp(i\alpha)\phi_+ \\
 \phi_- &\to \exp(-i\alpha)\phi_-,
\end{align*}
which leaves the lagrangian invariant, as required. The electric charge $Q$ is conserved, where $Q$ is the operator that generates this transformation.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. May I ask one more question? If I somehow want to look at the free theory of a "neutron", I will simply have $\mathcal{L} = \bar{n}(i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} - m) n$, but in this case we can have a $U(1)$ symmetry on this "neutron" free theory. Therefore it seems to me that at the level of neutron free theory we can assign charge on it. However, when it comes to pion-proton-neutron theory, it seems like we can not assign a charge on the neutron. What is the discrepancy between all of this? Thanks!

Comment: @ocf001497 The discrepancy is resolved by context. In the free-neutron theory that you wrote in the comment, there is indeed a conserved quantity: the number of neutrons. The $U(1)$ symmetry corresponds to that conserved quantity. At the level of *free* theories, we can't distinguish between the "neutron number" and "electric charge" interpretations, because there's no EM field to provide that context. Similarly, if we omit the EM field from the proton-neutron-pion theory, the only justification for the "electric charge" interpretation is by comparison to a richer theory that has an EM field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So does it mean that in the pion-proton-neutron theory without EM field, the conserve quantity we obtained by the U(1) symmetry that you provided, somehow indeed corresponds to the “electric charge”? Even though if we want to do it carefully, we should study a pion-proton-neutron theory with EM fields? Thanks!

Comment: @ocf001497  I don't have Coleman's lectures on hand, but I assume that he constructed the lagrangian so that it would be consistent with the known electric charges of the objects involved. We don't have to include an EM field for the model to be useful (because the strong force is much stronger), but without an EM field, the model itself doesn't know that the conserved quantity should be interpreted as electric charge. The same model (at least the part shown in the question) is also invariant under a different $U(1)$ transformation that treats $n$ as "charged" and $p$ as "neutral."